# Using head and tail command in unix to extract items from a file

Tags: unix, ubuntu-14.04

I'm currently new to the field of filters in unix and only having been introduced to basic commands in unix.

I have a file emp.lst which consists of following details in my ubuntu

```
cat emp.lst

2233|a.k.shukla|g.m.|sales|12/12/52|6000
9876|jai sharma|direcor|production|12/03/50|7000
5678|sumit chakraborty|d.g.m|marketing|19/04/43|6000
2365|barun sengupta|director|personnel|11/05/47|7800
5423|n.k. gupta|chairman|admin|30/08/56|5400
1006|chanchal singhvi|director|sales|03/09/38|6700
6213|karuna ganguly|g.m.|accounts|05/06/62|6300
1265|s.n. dasgupta|manager|sales|12/09/63|5600
4290|jayant choudhary|executive|production|07/09/50|6000
2476|anil aggarwal|manager|sales|01/05/59|5000
6521|lalit chowdary|director|marketing|26/09/45|8200
3212|shyam saksena|d.g.m.|accounts|12/12/55|6000
3564|sudhir aggarwal|executive|personnel|06/07/47|7500
2345|j.b.saxena|g.m.|marketing|12/03/45|8000
0110|v.k. agrawal|g.m.|marketing|31/12/40|9000
```

Now, i have understood that head extracts the top contents of this file and tail is used to access bottom contents.

```
$head -3 emp.lst returns the first 3 rows in the file emp.lst
```

similarly,
    $tail -2 emp.lst returns the last 2 rows in the file

Now, if i were to extract both of them together i.e first 3 rows from head and last 2 rows from tail? Is there anyway this can be achieved?

I also tried $head -3 emp.lst; tail -2 emp.lst \This achieves the required result but i think the ; is only used to type multiple commands in a single line
and also $head -3 emp.lst | tail -2  does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
(head -3; tail -2) < emp.lst
```

if you want to verify the line number you can do

```
cat emp.lst | nl | (head -3; tail -2)
```

Comment: Works! Nice, Thank you Sir

Comment: @Dominique I don't have WSL ready now but when I got home I can test it. it works on my suse and redhat containers